# sql query splitt a column into two

Tags: mysql, database

```
select ClientID,  
case 
when locate('Rate-Limit',CurrentAttributes) > 0 then substring_index(substring_in)
```

There will be three columns in the output, **'ClientID'**, **'attribute'** and **'value'**.

I came up with this but did not work for me.

In the clients table, '**CurrentAttributes**' may have multiple attribute/value pairs separated by semicolons. These pairs will have the attribute, an equals sign, followed by the value. 
`(For example in "framed-ip-address=192.168.68.5", 'framed-ip-address' will be the attribute and '192.168.68.5' will be the value)`.

When there are multiple attribute/value pairs in the column, another row must be output for each pair. For example, if a row with a ClientID of "1111" had "Rate-Limit=9216k/9216k 9216k/9216k 9216k/9216k 120/120;\n framed-ip-address=192.168.68.5;" in the "CurrentAttributes" column, I would be looking for the query to output two rows

First row:

```
ClientID:1111
attribute:Rate-Limit
value:9216k/9216k 9216k/9216k 9216k/9216k 120/120
```

Second row:

```
ClientID:1111
attribute:framed-ip-address
value:192.168.68.5
```

Comment: do you know the possible attribute names beforehand ?

Comment: (client id,   current attributes)

Comment: these are the table attributes before and after conversion split it into ( client id     ,rate limit  ,    framed ip adress)

Comment: any one have answer